# how to show product id included in url on product listing page?

Tags: url-rewrite, magento-2.1.3, product-page, geturl

I am using magnto2.1.3. i want to show my product id in url on product listing page.below is what i need.
[image]

how to achieve this?kindly help me please?

Comment: You can add ID to Url-key manually for each product. Or use third-party extensions such as SEO Suite Template for automatically updating product URL keys using pattern. But, in both cases your product URLs will be replaced anywhere, not only in the product list pages.

Comment: cant i achieve it programmatically?

Comment: i want to know that how to achieve this functionality pro grammatically and which file i need to change for this?

Comment: i have tried manually from seo url rewites but its not working but is there any programming trick to achieve this?

Comment: any reply please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento add URL-rewrite for product here:
Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver

In your extension you should add "before" plugin for execute method.
[See magento tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

In your plugin method you should add:

`$product->setUrlKey($product->getUrlKey() . '_' . $product->getId());`

(Of course, also you can add some checks for exists product ID in URL key for avoid
`[url_key]_[id]_[id]_[id]`

P.S. This method will not modify URL-key attribute (because product was saved before), but will modify URL rewrite.
P.S.2. You can use around plugin and after creating URL rewrite set original URL-key for product for avoid some conflicts.

Comment: can you please explain in detail like what initially i have to start with.iam newbie to magento2.1.3 so dont have much idea about customization....can you please explain in brief like how i suppose to start?for a newbie like me it would be really helpful.

thank in advance

Comment: I won't be able to tell about creation of the extension and a plug-in it is better, than a official manual. If you have specific question you can ask me.

Comment: ok i have created a custom module name yogesh\ProductClass

now which class file i should override here?is it ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver.php.if yes shall i create __construct function and write my code in order to use that code and the second step that u mentioned is to set original url key for product to avoid conflicts.i mean whats that and how to achieve this?

Comment: do i have to override observer class here?

Comment: Please see the example: [github](https://github.com/sergei-sss/m2_mod_urlrewrite)

Comment: Then we use plugin, magento generate special Intercepter class (var\generation\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver\Interceptor.php) This class will be used instead original observer class. But this interceptor class extends original observer also. For "before" plugin the interceptor class will call all plugin, which will modify argument and after will  call original observer method using new argument value (in our case - modified product object).

Comment: so do i need to install this plugin and test sir like other modules

Comment: thank u sir i i wlll try and test this for sure

Comment: sir i have applied the same method like i have create directory
in  app/code/Shelltag/ProductUrlRewrite
and create plugin in plugin folder ModifyProductUrlKeyPlugin.php and applied same code...i have upgraded thru command line setup:upgrade and check but the url is the same.i cant see any id in my product url sir
what might be teh reason

Comment: Are you sure, that the custom module was enabled?

Comment: Run this commands:  
php bin/magento module:enable Shelltag_ProductUrlRewrite  
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated  
rm -rf var/generation  

Is there Shelltag_ProductUrlRewrite in the extension list in magento Admin area (Stores->Configuration->Advanced)?  

If yes - check plugin beforeExecute method execution while product saving.

Comment: i have run module:status and its showing enabled
Shelltag_ProductUrlRewrite
now as you said i will disable module again:
 module:disable Shelltag_ProductUrlRewrite  and re-enable and run setup-upgrade --keep-generated rm -rf var/generation and will infomr u sir

Comment: yes sir my Shelltag_productUrlRewrite is listed in advance option and i have deleted var/generation/catalogrewrite and re run setup:upgrade than also the product id is not visible on product detail page inside url

Comment: also my cache is disabled already magento2.1.3

Comment: do i have to add new products from my admin in order to reflect changes sir or it will affect already installed products..?

Comment: Of course, you should save new products or re-save already installed products (you can use any magento product mass action). Before, test it for new product.

Comment: ok sir i will do the same and inform u..that extension is listed in advance admin area and enabled

Comment: thats awesome some worked fine..now if i want same functionality on category page like to show category id in url,do i have to achieve this using same functionality and classes or i need different functions to call for showing category id...after this i iwll mark this query as resolved and give up marks ir..thanks a ton

Comment: You should create one more plugin for Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\CategoryProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver with analog functionality (using category object instead product ).

Comment: sir cud be state the functions that i have to replace with product and which function i suppose to use instead beforeExecute () or i have to use same function beforeExecute for category?

Comment: See [github](https://github.com/sergei-sss/m2_mod_urlrewrite)

Comment: yes sir i have seen that is for product rewrite..i just want to know that i have to replace product with category and what changes i need to do sir..and do i need to use function beforeExecute() in it too?

Comment: I have updated example on github fot category URL Key

Comment: ok great sir and 1 last thing i wud like to know suppose my category url link is  http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags.html
and i want to replace .html with my category id..i.e i dont want to show .html on category page i wud like to show as
 http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags-34

Comment: do i need to use str_replace() function?? if yes than how to imply sir just a hint is it like str_replace('.html',$id,'.html') or i have to use substr()

Comment: You can change category URL Key suffix using magento setting: Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Search Engine Optimization->Category URL Suffix

Comment: but sir this option "Search Engine Optimization-" is not available in my configuration dashboard

Comment: its available sir just iam unable to see it..thank u

Comment: do i have to edit or create category in order to view the changes sir?

Comment: sir when i have tried using your way iam unable to get the result for category id apart from that my earlier product id at product url page have gone

Comment: i have got back the product id but category id still unable to see even after adding new category on category page. and yes i have unselected .html on category page..is this is the cause??

Comment: I have checked category URL - it really do not work, sorry for wrong way. Magento use different way for saving  product and category URLs. I didn't find solution for the category.

Comment: Please, check question as solved, because it about product URL and it works. Try add new question about category URL. Good luck.

Comment: ok sir i iwll mark it as solved